# Using MongoDB, how do you seach for a word or phrase in a text field?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am currently storing a set of documents in MongoDB which look like this:

```
{
  "_id": { "$oid": "234kjbj23b4kjbkjb23b4kj324" },
  "UserName": "John Doe",
  "Body": {
    "Text": "This is Manchester City Football Club",
    "Timestamp": { "$date": { "$numberLong": "12344532345324" } },
    "MessageId": {
      "$binary": { "base64": "Hqwej43riojr3o4iij34r==", "subType": "03" }
    }
  }
}
```

I am wanting to use the MongoDB filter to be able to seach for a word or phrase in the Body.Text field. This is what my code currently looks like:

```
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Bson;

var collection = client.GetDatabase("Database").GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Collection");
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Body.Text", "Manchester City");
var document = collection.Find(filter).First();
```

This currently returns nothing as it is looking for an exact match so if I were to alter it to `Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Body.Text", "This is Manchester City Football Club");` it would return the correct document - however I want to find it by searching for a word or phrase within the Body.Text field and not by an exact match.

I was previously doing it using regex like this:

```
var regexPattern = $".*{"Manchester City"}.*";
Regex r = new Regex(regexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
filter &= Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Regex(x => x.Body.Text, r);
```

However when doing it this way I get a performace advisory saying `Regex queries are not able to efficiently use indexes, consider using Atlas Search.`

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you need can be achieved with [Atlas Search](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/tutorial/). After setting it up, you could search your word like :

```
var collection = client.GetDatabase("YourDb").GetCollection<BsonDocument>("YourCollectionName");
var searchOptions = new BsonDocument
{
    { "text", new BsonDocument
        {
            { "query", "Manchester City" },
            { "path", "Body.Text" }
        }
    }
};

var searchFilter = new BsonDocument("$search", searchOptions);
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Match(searchFilter);
var document = collection.Find(filter).First();
```

Comment: Thank you. I have followed the instructions to setup a default Atlas Search - however when I try and run the above I get an error saying `'FilterDefinitionBuilder<BsonDocument>' does not contain a definition for 'Match'`